# How to Hide linkButton inasp.net when value=0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable linkbutton when I found  value=0 in asp.net and want to visible label with 0 value.

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some JS Code at the javasccript pageLoad that loops all link buttons using CssClass(add dummy css class if not exists).

```
        function pageLoad() {
            $('.lbClassName').each(function (item) {
                if ($(item).val() == '0') {
                    $(item).prop('disabled', true);
                }
            })
        }
```